# How to set items width inside the Box component in Material UI React?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I use React Material UI and it's Box component to styling my form.
In my case I have 4 items in each row but in last row I need to show 3 items and the last item should fill the row.
In other word the last 2 elements must be merged.
How can I do that when Box component devided all my rows to 4 column?

my code:

```
<Box
    sx={{
       display: 'grid',
       columnGap: 2,
       rowGap: 3,
       gridTemplateColumns: {xs: 'repeat(7, 1fr)',
       sm: 'repeat(4, 1fr)'},
         }}
  >
first row with 4 columns:

    <TextField ....>
    <TextField ....>
    <TextField ....>
    <TextField ....>

second row with 3 columns:

    <TextField ....>
    <TextField ....>
    //This column should be spanned for two columns.
    <TextField ....>

</Box>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this grid layout:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { Box, TextField } from "@mui/material";

export default function Grid() {
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        display: "grid",
        gridTemplateAreas: "'a1 a2 a3 a4' 'b1 b2 c c'"
      }}
    >
      {/* first row with 4 columns: */}
      <TextField style={{ gridArea: "a1" }} />
      <TextField style={{ gridArea: "a2" }} />
      <TextField style={{ gridArea: "a3" }} />
      <TextField style={{ gridArea: "a4" }} />
      {/* second row with 3 columns: */}
      <TextField style={{ gridArea: "b1" }} />
      <TextField style={{ gridArea: "b2" }} />
      {/* This column should be spanned for two columns. */}
      <TextField style={{ gridArea: "c" }} />
    </Box>
  );
}
```